# javascript what wrong in my function?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript function to hide or show element but it's not working:

```
function detail(e) {
    var parent = e.parentNode;
    var next = parent.nextSibling;
    if (next.style.display == 'none') {
        row.style.display = '';
    } else {
        row.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

can anyone help me about this problem ?

thanks

Comment: where is `row` coming from?

Comment: In the `if` true branch try `row.style.display = "block";`.

Comment: it's still not working, error happened when statement next.style.display, why ??

Comment: What's the error message? Is `next` defined when the error occurs?

Comment: Can you show your selector query? Aka row.... The code is fine but we need to see a larger scope of the code.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your peoblem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript nextSibling is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588071/javascript-nextsibling-is-not-working)

Comment: Create Fiddle for your problem it is Confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.nextSibling` selects a TEXT_NODE (nodeType = 3), not the next `tr`

Try this:

```
var next = parent.nextSibling;
while (next.nodeType != 1) {
   next = next.nextSibling;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are checking for 'display == none', then use:

```
function detail(e) {
    var parent = e.parentNode;
    var next = parent.nextSibling;
    if (next.style.display == 'none') {
        next.style.display = '';
    } else {
        next.style.display = 'none';
   }   
}
```

If not, then what is 'row'?

Comment: problem when program execute "next.style.display", why ??

Comment: What is the problem? I need more detail.

Comment: I have two tr and one td, detail(e) where e is td, I call parentNode to get tr first, and call nextSibling to get second tr, but it's not working. Can anyone explain to me ? thanks,

Comment: Can you show the value of `next.nodeType`? Some browsers insert TEXT_NODE for whitespaces.

Comment: next.nodeType give value = 3, what's problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to show/hide a div element.

```
function fun(){
    var ele = document.getElementById("testDiv");
    if(ele.className==="show"){
        ele.className="hide";
    }
    else{
        ele.className="show";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imrukhan/7j8ZS/1/

Better if you provide a complete html.