# Javascript nextSibling is not working

Tags: javascript, nextsibling

I have followed html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="link" onClick="detil_iklan(this)">AD2188914</td>
    <td>Seluruh Zona 468x60 - Global Gambar</td>
    <td>41.100.000</td>
    <td>4.440.100</td>
    <td>0.005</td>
    <td>Rp. 1.250.000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="border_bottom detil_iklan" style="display:none">
    <td colspan="6">AD2188914</td>
</tr>
```

I have followed javascript:

```
function detil_iklan(e) {
        var parent = e.parentNode;
        var next = parent.nextSibling;
        if (next.style.display == 'none') {
            next.style.display = '';
        } else {
            next.style.display = 'none';
        }
        alert("fas");
    }
```

what wrong with my code ? When call detil_iklan(e), alert is not called. Can anyone help me ?

thanks,

Comment: Please update/edit your original question if you want to clarify it. And explain what exactly you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: Which dom element are you trying to run it on? Does it have a `parentNode.nextSibling`?

Comment: yes, parentNode.nextSibling, but why it's not working ?

Comment: @FelixKling "When call detil_iklan(e), alert is not called."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Added a function to find next sibling`**

```
function detil_iklan(e) {
    var parent = e.parentNode;
    var next = get_nextsibling(parent);
    if (next.style.display == 'none') {
            next.style.display = '';
        } else {
            next.style.display = 'none';
        }
}

//function to find next sibling  
function get_nextsibling(n) {
    x = n.nextSibling;
    while (x.nodeType != 1) {
        x = x.nextSibling;
    }
    return x;
}
```

## [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5RUa/)